# Microchip XC32 compiler, malloc call returns 0, writing to pointer throws Unimplemented RAM

Tags: c, embedded, malloc, microcontroller, pic

I'm coding on MPLAB, using the XC32 compiler, and trying to get the hang of using dynamic memory, so I created a basic example program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <plib.h>

char x;
char y;



char main(void)
{
    Nop();
    char *pLocation = (char *)malloc(16);
    if(pLocation == 0x00)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    for(x = 0;x<=7;x++)
    {
        *pLocation = x;
        pLocation++;

    }
    while(1)
    {

        Nop();
    }
}
```

Problems:

- When the pointer gets to the `malloc` call line, the value of `pLocation` is forced to 0x00 meaning that it somehow managed to fail to pass me pointer information from the heap.
- When the pointer gets to assigning the value of `x` to the location of the pointer `pLocation` I get a **Bus Exception** saying *Unimplemented RAM memory access*. I suspect this is because I tried to write to 0x00.

Am I doing something wrong in the code?

Additional Information:

- I have already assigned a heap of 16 bytes.
- I get the same error for memory requests of even size 2.
- I am using the MPLAB SIM debugger.
- MPLAB Version 8.87.00.00.
- Building with the XC32 compiler.

Comment: When you have a NULL pointer you shouldn't lament about umimplemented RAM access errors. What do you mead with "have assigned a heap of 16? If this means you have reserved 16 bytes for heap you should consider the necessary heap management. You will always have to reserve more memory than you want to malloc successfully.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a need to check for NULL after allocating memory, when kernel uses overcommit memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248995/is-there-a-need-to-check-for-null-after-allocating-memory-when-kernel-uses-over)

Comment: Thank you for your response harper, I agree that I will have to consider memory management however I need to get the malloc working first then I will play with the Free function. and I get the same error for malloc(2)

Comment: Hello osgx, thank you for your edit.
while NULL checks will definetly improve code habit, I dont think It is the cause of this problem, however I will go and add it now anyway =)

Comment: What do you mean with "I have already assigned a heap of 16"?

Comment: You can tell the linker script how many bytes you wish to allocate to the heap, so in Projects ->build options -> project, MPLAB XC32 Linker TAB, Under heap size I placed 16. Therefore the malloc command should be able to allocate 16 bytes.

Comment: What is sizeof(char) in your system? 1? 2? As mentioned above: A heap size of 16 might not be sufficient to handle malloc(16). Add a few bytes for overhead.

Comment: Size of char is 1 byte in this pic

Comment: @Axel:  sizeof(char) is always 1 regardless of the bit size of char.  The macro CHAR_BIT defines the bit width of char.  Moreover malloc() allocates a number of char sized memory locations so a heap allocation of 16 will always be too small because of heap management and alignment requirements.

Comment: @osgx - no, this is not a duplicate of that.  While the function name and a few ground rules might be the same, dynamic memory allocation on a tiny embedded system is practically quite different from what happens when running under a full featured operating system.  The real issue here is not the foolish mistake in trying after getting null as a return value, but that the this particular system is not properly configured for dynamic memory usage, causing malloc to return null.

Comment: Chris Stratton, in early version of the question there was no checking for null. This is kind of "something wrong in code".

Comment: @osgx:  That may be the case, but the problem in the first instance comes from allocating too small a heap. This is tagged embedded and refers to a system with no OS to provide memory management.  It is a developer requirement to allocate space for a heap in this case.  So it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have already assigned a heap of 16

That is insufficient heap space to support an allocation of 16 bytes.  An amount of space is required for heap management, and each allocation will have guaranteed alignment of typically 8 bytes to ensure alignment of 64 bit data types.

You should allocate far more heap than necessary, and certainly more than 16 bytes - for that you may as well use the stack or static allocation.

Typically you would want to allocate all available memory not used for other purposes (stack-space, statics, DMA pools etc.) to the heap since it will be unused otherwise (you might allow a little headroom so that in maintenance small changes to static allocation don't require you to change the heap size) ; but you can test my hypothesis simply by increasing the heap allocation to 1024 bytes for example.  If you don't have that much available, then your system really is not suited to supporting a heap at all perhaps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Clifford it seems that in this case it is 23 bytes of seperation for this systems and it doesnt really matter what type I cast its still 23 bytes. I guess that will always be the case since malloc returns a void pointer and doesnt really care about my requirement. Ofcourse the addresses skip accordingly if I do cast to an int for example.

Comment: Implementations differ, but generally when you perform a malloc, the number of bytes you requested plus a "header" is allocated from the heap.  The header is initialised with the data required for free-block management. The data comprises `<header><userdata>`, and the pointer returned is to <userdata>.  When free() is called, the pointer is decremented so that free() can access the `<header>` in order to return the block to the heap.  If the header is 8 bytes, your 16 byte allocation would use 24 bytes - and there would be no alignment padding in this case. 23 bytes seems unlikely.

Comment: Some implementations add information in the header for overflow and corruption detection.

Answer (score 0):

making the heap size >=32 solves this problem but I cant explain why. its probably linked to the fact that its a 32-bit pic in some way.

If any one can I would be thankful.

-----Edit-----

I have some further information, everytime I wish to place a new malloc call for a new pointer, I have to increase the heap by 32 even if I am not using all of it. also in the address these pointers are seperated by minimim 23! locations even if malloc request was anything between 1 and 8, then things just when you want more. but ofcourse if you are not careful one pointer enter the range of the other without a problem

Comment: It might be worth seriously considering doing explicit memory allocation, unless you are building a system which needs to continuously create and free data structures or objects.

Comment: Check your C library documentation, it should give information about minimum malloc alignment.  In this case it may be as much as 32 bytes. For a description of a typical implementation of malloc() see [here](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html).  In the end though you should not really need to worry about it, the heap is intended to be a (relatively) *large pool* of reusable memory, what you appear to be attempting to do is probably not a sensible use of the heap.

Comment: In my case the final deployment is being used for strings of unknown size. Although I personally dont think more than 50 characters will ever be used so yea I probably could have gone for static allocation but then I wouldn't have gotten any practise with this! =) The onboard memory of this particular PIC is 32KB.